# Creation of temp table to minus against actual table

Tags: sql

I am testing an ETL load at the moment and want to create a temporary table that combines a number of rules so that I can do a minus against this temp table and the actual loaded table.
I've tried various things but keep getting the same message stating "FROM keyword is not found where expected"
My mentor is off on holiday and would appreciate if someone can offer me some assistance.

```
Create table tbl_HT_CUST_PHNUM_TEMP as
Select a.CONT_ID as CONT_ID, 
a.TELEPHONE_NO as TELEPHONE_NO, 
ROW_ID IS NULL,
STATUS_ID IS NULL, 
SystemTableID IS NULL, 
INITIAL_POPULATION_TS as INITIAL_POPULATION_TS,
BUSINESS_DATE_EXT as BUSINESS_DATE_EXT, 
UPDATE_DATE_TIME as UPDATE_DATE_TIME,
DATE_ENDED as DATE_ENDED
CUSTOMERMAPPINGKEY IS NULL
from <schema>.tbl_HT_CUST_PHNUM a;
```

Comment: What is `CUSTOMERMAPPINGKEY IS NULL` supposed to mean?

Comment: What database are you using?  You should tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You have your `as`s confused with `is`s.  Assuming your database supports `create table as`, then I suspect you want something like this:

```
Create table tbl_HT_CUST_PHNUM_TEMP as
    Select a.CONT_ID as CONT_ID, 
           a.TELEPHONE_NO, 
           NULL as ROW_ID,
           NULL as STATUS_ID, 
           NULL as SystemTableID, 
           a.INITIAL_POPULATION_TS,
           a.BUSINESS_DATE_EXT, 
           a.UPDATE_DATE_TIME,
           a.DATE_ENDED,
           NULL as CUSTOMERMAPPINGKEY
    from <schema>.tbl_HT_CUST_PHNUM a;
```

Note that you don't need `as` to specify a column name that is coming directly from a table.